# Loading AngularJS controller code on state change using ui-router (lazily)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an AngularJS app with a Rails backend. Using the Rails asset pipeline, I've been able to organise my javascript files quite nicely, but I've landed at a point where the amount of javascript initially loaded is becoming large.

All my views are loaded asynchronously on state changes, but the controller code is already preloaded, while only one controller is being used on initial page load. I'm curious about whether this is the preferred way to go and if there are alternatives. Can I lazy-load this controller code in any way?

I've thought about using the `controllerProvider` state parameter, but I just can't wrap my head around how that would work.

Comment: Do you want to load your javascript files as required? Do you mean something like this?

Comment: You could put it like that. Ideally, I would want to specify the controller that's attached to the state as a file, which is then loaded.

Comment: There is one library called angularAMD. You can use that. It will load controller as per the route. Hope it will help

Comment: Hm, that looks like it could work. It's a little more invasive than I would have liked and I'm not sure how it would work together with ui-router, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I have used that.. it works with ui-router, too. The only problem will be, change will require in your existing code to support angularAMD